# Homeomorphism of the closed unit ball not preserving the sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Exercise 2.9.12 in Ronnie Brown's *Categories and Groupoids* asks the reader to show that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$  is continuous such that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism from the open unit ball to itself, then $f(S^{n-1}) \subseteq S^{n-1}$.

Not a particularly hard exercise, but at first I misread it as $f$ restricted to a homeomorphism from the closed unit ball to itself, and so I struggled for a bit. This made me wonder if there was a counterexample for that statement. That is,

**Does there exist $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism from the closed unit ball to itself, but $f(S^{n-1}) \not \subseteq S^{n-1}$?**

Comment: No, there isn't. Boundary points and interior points are topologically different, so every homeomorphism of a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ preserves the boundary and the interior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In fact, there is a more general result:

**Theorem:** Let $M$ and $N$ be topological manifolds with boundaries and let $F:M\to N$ be a homeomorphism. Then, $F(\partial M)=\partial N$.

The proof follows from the fact that a point in a topological manifold is either a boundary point or an interior point, but not both.